# Convert Oracle PL/SQL to Mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

how can I convert the following structure :

```
for i in (select distinct rr.date_ as dater 
          from REGULATORYR rr, country c 
          where rr.date_>=datedebut 
          and rr.date_<= datefin 
           and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_
            and c.name_= pays
            order by rr.date_ )
loop
```

Comment: You should not keep adding to the question by comments in answers. BTW mysql does not have for loops or TYPEs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert oracle for loop to mysql loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738374/convert-oracle-for-loop-to-mysql-loop)

Answer (score 0):

This should be the answer about your question:

```
declare i cursor for select distinct rr.date_ as dater 
          from REGULATORYR rr, country c 
          where rr.date_>=datedebut 
          and rr.date_<= datefin 
           and c.pk_=rr.countrypk_
            and c.name_= pays
            order by rr.date_;
open i;
fetch i into;
while not_found=0
do
```